# Flot chart: How to remove/hide tick values along y-axis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, bar-chart, flot

I want to remove tick values (3.5, 3.0, 2.5, 2.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0) along y-axis. For more information please see below picture. If can not remove then there must be some option to change the color. I will make it transparent.

[image]

```
var data = [{data: [[0,1]], color: "red"},
            {data: [[1,2]], color: "yellow"},
            {data: [[2,3]], color: "green"}];

$.plot("#placeholder",data, {
    series: {
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.3,
            align: "center",
            lineWidth: 0,
            fill:.75
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        ticks: [[0,"Red"],[1,"Yellow"],[2,"Green"]]
    }
});
```

Here is the example I am following for this: http://jsfiddle.net/TPp8m/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set yAxis ticks as an array to get only those values, for your question I added

```
yAxis{
ticks: [] 
}
```

Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPp8m/186/)

Answer (score 0):

As you said , You just want to **hide all y axis values** than you can  Use  `$("#placeholder").find(".tickLabel").hide();`

*and show it again Using:*

`$("#placeholder").find(".tickLabel").show();`

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TPp8m/187/)